# ImportError: cannot import name 'UserForm'

Tags: python, django

I'm using pretty much the same code that I have already gotten to work in a different project so I can't really pinpoint the problem other then it looks to be coming from something in my URLs as it pertains to the views? Other than that I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error. Please help.

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks_run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/colors/colors/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from accounts import views
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/colors/accounts/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from accounts.forms import UserForm
ImportError: cannot import name 'UserForm'
```

Form.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import User

class UserFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from accounts.forms import UserForm

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request.user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account now active")

        else:
            print("Login Unsuccessful")
            return HttpResponse("Your username and/or password are not correct")

    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/login.html',{})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request,'accounts/register.html',{'user_form':user_form,'registered':registered})

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from accounts import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/',views.user_logout,name='user_logout'),
]
```

project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from accounts import views
#from colorsets import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
#    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

Let me know if you need to see anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `forms.py`. You have `UserFrom` instead of `UserForm`.

Comment: That was simple, I dyslexia so I really appreciate the help even though it was so basic.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you think its coming from your urls.py, but

Your trace indicates 
`File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/colors/accounts/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from accounts.forms import UserForm`

Thus the error is coming from view.py line2....

```
1) from django.shortcuts import render
2) from accounts.forms import UserForm
3)
4) from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
```

double check your import...use the django interactive shell if necessary (running each line to see if it works or not)

Answer (score 0):

Change **line 2** of your views.py file from

```
    from accounts.forms import UserForm
                To
    from <appname> import Form
```

Comment: could you add a short explanation on why it would help the OP?